# Open new tab in Krusader from command line

Tags: command-line, krusader

How do I open the current directory from command line in a new tab in an existing [Krusader](http://www.krusader.org/) window?

The following command will open a brand new windows (process), which is not what I want:

```
krusader .
```

Comment: does `krusader --left .` work? Or does it still open brand new instance of krusader, merely with current directory?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it still opens a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

In Settings->Startup make sure that 'Single instance mode' is checked. Than `krusader .` opens new panel on left side in current working directory.

To use some nice alias add this to ~/bashrc:

```
krusader_here() {
    yakuake_pid=`pgrep yakuake`

    if [ "s$yakuake_pid" != "s" ]; then
        in_yakuake_pstree=`pstree -p $yakuake_pid | grep $$`
        if [ "s$in_yakuake_pstree" != "s" ]; then
            qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/window org.kde.yakuake.toggleWindowState
        fi
    fi

    krusader --left=`pwd` &
}

alias k='krusader_here'
```

I run it quite often from yakuake in 'always on top' mode and this script just disappears it automatically.